# Generating mutliple pdf files using mpdf but only one is generated

Tags: php, loops, mpdf

I want to generate multiple files using mpdf library, but unfortunately, only one file is generated, instead of multiple, how can I do this. Thanks for showing your interest.

```
for ($i=1; $i<count($sheetData); $i++)
 {
  $name = $sheetData[$i][0];
  $fName = $sheetData[$i][1];
                      
  $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => [290, 236]]);
  $stylesheet = file_get_contents('../assets/css/style.css');
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
  ob_end_clean();
                       
  $html = $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>My Layout is there</p>');
  $filename = time().'.pdf';
  $mpdf->Output($filename ,'D');
  unset($mpdf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save them. U cant output them all at once with "D" or "I"

```
$mpdf->Output($filename ,'F');
```

if need one file with addPage() https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpage.html

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => [290, 236]]);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($sheetData); $i++) {
    $name = $sheetData[$i][0];
    $fName = $sheetData[$i][1];

    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('../assets/css/style.css');

    if ($i > 1) {
        $mpdf->AddPage();
    }
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>My Layout is there</p>');


}

$filename = 'my.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($filename, 'F');
```

u can also create html first

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => [290, 236]]);
$html = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < count($sheetData); $i++) {
    $name = $sheetData[$i][0];
    $fName = $sheetData[$i][1];
    
    $html .=  '<p>My Layout is there</p>';
    
}

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../assets/css/style.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$filename = 'my.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($filename, 'D');
```

Comment: change d to f but it throwing an error. Notice: ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in

Comment: remove ob_end_clean() should not be a problem

Comment: you solved my problem, now multiple files are generated but I want to save them into the single file instead of saving individualy

Comment: i have edited my answer for creating one file

Comment: Still, it's generating multiple files

Comment: the first or second example?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send multiple PDF files to the client or to save them on disk?

You're using `time()` as a pseudo-random filename, but if the generation of the PDF files is fast enough and happens in the same second, you will overwrite the previously generated file, at least if you choose to store the resulting file on disk. You may want to use something like `"generated_$i"` instead of `time()`.

Comment: Yes, I want to save them locally on my pc.

Comment: In that case, you need to change the 'D' to 'F' as mentioned in the comment of @Delete and change the `time()` to a better value.

Comment: I added rand key with time so there is no chance of overriding the same file name. ~~~$key = rand(1,10000);
                      $filename = $key.''.time().'.pdf';~~~

Comment: @HadiNiazi What you can also use, is `hrtime(true)` instead of the rand() + time() concatenation. You can also make a truncated hash from it to make sure the length is always fixed: `substr(hash('sha256', hrtime(true)), 0, 12);`

Comment: Good idea, I'll try this, can you please suggest how can I solve generating files multiple issues.

Comment: u have $i there u can add that should be unique to filename $filename = $i . '-' . time() .'.pdf';

Comment: @HadiNiazi The trunacted hash approach will resolve the problem with duplicate filenames. You also need to remove the `ob_end_clean();`. What problem do you still have?

Comment: The issue is resolved, now multiple files are generating but I want to put them into one file. (one file contains multiple files on different pages)